# Iterating over a list and joining items of same type

Tags: python, string, list

I have a bunch of strings shoved into lists via `list(string)`:

```
stringy = "I've 24got a 697love-a-ly2 bunch of 000coconuts!"
listy = list(stringy)
```

Where `listy` looks like:

```
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '2', '4', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '6', '9'...
```

I'm looking for a cleaner way to iterate through the list and, without throwing out any of the individual character entries, join together all of the integers to produce:

```
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '697','l','o'...
```

Where the integers are going to be in the strings is not predictable, and the number of digits in the number is also not predictable (I could run into 1 or 1000000000.)

To find the integer values in the first place thought about something like:

```
for i in listy:
    if i.isdigit():
        x = listy.index(i)
        z = listy[x+1]
        if z.isdigit():
```

...but that's just going to be an inefficient bloody mess.

Actually putting the numbers together is going to be pretty easy but I am having trouble coming up with a neat way to check each number. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a side note: Never, never use `listy.index(i)` to get back the indices from the values. Besides being much slower, it's also not going to work. If there are two elements with the value `'2'`, `index('2')` is always going to find the first one. Just do `for x, i in enumerate(listy):` instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this pretty simply using [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html),

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "I've 24got a 697love-a-ly2 bunch of 000coconuts!"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|.', a)
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '697', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', '-', 'a', '-', 'l', 'y', '2', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', '000', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'u', 't', 's', '!']
```

If you are doing this operation multiple times you should consider compiling it like,

```
>>> splitter = re.compile(r'\d+|.')
```

Comment: Thank you! For the sake of my education- since I've never used reg expressions- is there another way? This is for an assignment, and I'd prefer to spend more time learning about them than I have, so that when I use them, I can use them with a full understanding of what they do and how they work.

Comment: `\d` matches digits, `+` means one or more of the previous item (so one or more number), `|` is or, and `.` is any character. So the expression means "one or more number OR any character"

Comment: You can also do `'\d+|\D'` which means "one or more digits OR a single non-digit character". The posted solution depends on `\d+` coming first.

Comment: Note that this answer is only useful when starting with a string. When starting with a list (such as when finding this question through its title), look at the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (disclaimer: I use it for everything..)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> tick = count()
>>> [''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(sy, lambda c: c.isdigit() or next(tick))]
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '697', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', '-', 'a', '-', 'l', 'y', '2', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', '000', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'n', 's', '!']
```

`groupby` splits a sequence into contiguous groups using a key function.  In this case, my keyfunction is `c.isdigit() or c`, which will return True for digits and the character for nondigits.  As @gnibbler points out, though, we need to be careful that we don't accidentally merge contiguous characters either..

On second though, we don't need the `count` trick:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> gg = ([''.join(group)] if key else list(group) for key, group in groupby(sy, str.isdigit))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(gg))
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '697', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', '-', 'a', '-', 'l', 'y', '2', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', '000', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'n', 's', '!']
```

Comment: Ah itertools, is there anything you're not good at? Well... anything Python as a language is idiomatically capable of.

Comment: I don't use `groupby` for _everything_ … but when I see a question that says "I have a sequence of foo, and I want to join/group/whatever the ones that bar", it's hard _not_ to immediately think `groupby`…

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use itertools." Now they have `next(takewhile(not_, count()))` problems.

Comment: Doesn't work for `sy = "I've 24got a 697love-a-ly2 bunch of 000balloons!"`

Comment: Nice fix getting rid of the lambda

Comment: For the `count` trick, I make it a "default parameter" to the lambda to keep it local

Comment: I don't think you need the `list(group)`. Just use `group`

Comment: `[i for key, group in groupby(sy, str.isdigit) for i in ([''.join(group)] if key else group)]` then you don't need `chain.from_iterable` either

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to pop() characters off a reversed list (or stack):

```
>>> groups = []
>>> rlisty = list(reversed(listy))
>>> while rlisty:
    char = rlisty.pop()
    groupedchar = char
    while rlisty: # Look ahead for digits
        # Take next char from rlist
        nextchar = rlisty.pop()
        if nextchar.isdigit():
            groupedchar += nextchar # Group digits together
        else:
            # Put back into list for next loop
            rlisty.append(nextchar)
            break

    groups.append(groupedchar)   

>>> groups
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' 24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' 697', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', '-', 'a', '-', 'l', 'y2', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' 000', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'u', 't', 's', '!']
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being down-voted for using a c-style solution (instead of pythonic list comps), here is an easy to read solution:

```
>>> stringy = "I've 24got a 697love-a-ly2 bunch of 000coconuts!"
>>> x = list(stringy)
>>> i = 0
>>> l = []
>>> while i < len(x):
        t = ''
        while x[i].isdigit():
                t += x[i]
                i += 1
        if t:
                l.append(t)
                i -= 1
        else:
                l.append(x[i])
        i += 1


>>> l
['I', "'", 'v', 'e', ' ', '24', 'g', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', '697', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', '-', 'a', '-', 'l', 'y', '2', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', '000', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'u', 't', 's', '!']
>>>
```

The only confusing part might be the `i -= 1`.  That's just there so that `i` doesn't get double-incremented when the inner while loop does its thing, and then the outer increments again.