# How to compare consecutive elements in a list of dictionaries and merge elements based on a condition?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary elements we'll call "sessions", in each session, there is a list of "parts", a session mode and time stamps:

```
sessions_arr = [
    {'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632705871, 'TS_end': 1632706202},
    {'parts': [3, 4], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706303},
    {'parts': [5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706304, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
    {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500}
]
```

If consecutive sessions have the same "session_mode" then the parts in the matching sessions need to merge into the same element, so I want the output to look like this:

```
sessions_arr = [ 
    {'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632705871, 'TS_end': 1632706202},
    {'parts': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
    {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500}
]
```

Notice how the `TS_end` of the 2nd index of the array was also updated accordingly. I also want to always merge back and only if the elements are consecutive.

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(len(sessions_arr_copy) - 1):
    if sessions_arr[i]['session_mode'] == sessions_arr[i + 1]['session_mode']:
        # if they match move that session into the one before it
        sessions_arr[i]['parts'].extend(sessions_arr[i+1]['parts'])
        sessions_arr[i]['TS_end'] = sessions_arr[i+1]['TS_end']
        sessions_arr.pop(i+1)
```

The issue with this implementation is that when I go to pop the element that I just merged into the previous element, it changes the size of the list that I am comparing through. I know this is an `IndexError` and I understand why this error is occuring. I just want to know how to go about working around this. I would like to do this with only one `for` loop as the size of the list can get pretty big but it doesn't have to be the fastest algorithm either.

Comment: The simplest solution would be instead of merging the list items in-place, to create a new list.

Comment: Instead of modifying the current dict and list that you are iterating on, create a new dict with the required information and append it to a new list.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533693) might be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you try to change the list during iteration. I would use a new array and form the attributes inside.

```
sessions_arr = [
    {'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632705871, 'TS_end': 1632706202},
    {'parts': [3, 4], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706303},
    {'parts': [5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706303, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
    {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500}
]
    
helper = []
idx = 0
is_consecutive = lambda sess1, sess2: sess1['session_mode'] == sess2['session_mode']
helper.append(sessions_arr[0])
for item in sessions_arr[1:]:
    if is_consecutive(helper[idx], item):
        helper[idx]['parts'].extend(item['parts'])
        helper[idx]['TS_end'] = item['TS_end']
    else:
        helper.append(item)
        idx += 1

print(helper)
```

Output:

```
[{'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632705871, 'TS_end': 1632706202},
 {'parts': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
 {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500}]
>
```

Comment: Not sure if by referring to consecutive you meant to item `i.TS_end == i+1.TS_start` as a condition.

Comment: I like this solution as I don't have to learn how to use itertools and the answer is simple as well. One thing to change is the second condition you have in is_consecutive : "sess1['TS_end'] == sess2['TS_start']". This condition does not apply to my case as the TS_end and TS_start of consecutive sessions with the same session mode may not be the same. Other than that though this solves my problem so thanks.

Comment: @ahmedmohammed I'll edit my solution then. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would break this into two parts:

1. A function that knows how to merge a set of dicts to create a singe merged dict.
2. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the list on the key you want.

Together that might look something like:

```
from itertools import groupby

def merge(dicts):
    merged_parts = [part for line in dicts for part in line['parts']]
    start = dicts[0] ['TS_start']
    end = dicts[-1]['TS_end']

    return {
        'parts': merged_parts, 
        'session_mode':dicts[0]['session_mode'], 
        'TS_start': start,
        'TS_end': end
    }
                    

sessions_arr = [
    {'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632705871, 'TS_end': 1632706202},
    {'parts': [3, 4], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706303},
    {'parts': [5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706303, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
    {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500},
]

[merge(list(g)) for k, g, in groupby(sessions_arr, key=lambda d: d['session_mode'])]
```

This will leave you with a new list looking like:

```
[
  {'parts': [1, 2], 'session_mode': 'Driving','TS_start': 1632705871,'TS_end': 1632706202},
  {'parts': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'session_mode': 'Idling', 'TS_start': 1632706203, 'TS_end': 1632706400},
  {'parts': [7], 'session_mode': 'Driving', 'TS_start': 1632706401, 'TS_end': 1632706500}
]
```

If your groups are large, you could improve this by not requiring the creation of the temp `list(g)` and making the `merge()` function just accept an iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will have to learn itertools now seems very useful. I was hoping to solve this problem without importing any libraries which is why I went with @Linial's answer